# Python Tumblr Uploader Bot (with twill)

Tags: python, tumblr, twill

So I making a Tumblr bot in python with twill (yea I know I could use API, but i want to use multiple accounts (50+) and I don't want to create an API for every account))

And how can I make the uploading procedure through twill? I succesfully log in.

My Code:

```
site = ("http://tumblr.com/login")

def PhotoUpload():
    twill.commands.go("http://www.tumblr.com/new/photo")
    twill.commands.submit()

def ShowInfo():
    print twill.commands.info()
    print twill.commands.showforms()
    print twill.commands.showlinks()

def Login():
    twill.commands.go(site)
    twill.commands.fv("1","signup_email","test@test.com")
    twill.commands.fv("1","signup_password",password)
    twill.commands.submit()

def Main():  
    Login()
    PhotoUpload()

Main()
```

Comment: The documentation for twill says that there's a `formfile` command. Does that do what you need to do? http://twill.idyll.org/commands.html

Comment: Sadly, the tumblr's photo upload isn't working that way, as I found :\ I checked the forms at the tumblr.com/new/photo page, and there isn't any form for files.